# CSS/Django - Display block as if buttons are present

Tags: html, css, django

everyone.
In my django I have 2 options:

[image]

[image]

I want to be list with admin/user always on the right, like in my second jpeg.

HTML:

```
<body>
            <div class="container2">
                <div class="butts">
                    <form action="{% url 'catalog:redir' %}" method="post">

                        <button class="butt" type="submit">
                            <p>
                                На главную
                            </p>
                        </button>
                    </form>
                    <div>
                        {% if author_list.1 %}
                        <div>
                        <form action="{% url 'catalog:author_delete' author_list.1.id %}" method="post">

                            <button class="butt" type="submit">
                                <p>
                                    Новая раздача
                                </p>
                            </button>
                        </form>
                      </div>  
                    </div>
                </div>
                {% endif %}
                <div class="voted-users">
                    {% if author_list|length == 0 %}
                    <p>Игра не началась</p>
                    {% else %}
                    {% if voted_list %}

                    </ul>
                    {% else %}
                    <p>Непроголосовавшие пользователи</p>
                    <ul>
                        {% for i in user_list %}
                        <p> {{ i }} <p>
                                {% endfor %}
                    </ul>
                    {% endif %}
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
```

CSS:

```css
.butts {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.butt {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container2 {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

The page is done using flexbox. Don't have any idea.
It looks, like if my IF doesnt work my second div gets into first div (voted users into butts), but in the other case it doesnt happen

Comment: So -- `{%` tags don't exist in `HTML` ..  This looks like a `Django` template to me?

Comment: It is. I mentioned that

Comment: @Zak The question does mention that django is used.

Comment: I added the django tag to the question ..  At first glance it appeared to be a html/css question.  -- Also note . I would add the label `Django` to the title of the question to get more pertinent answers/help ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot about closing tag

```
                    <button class="butt" type="submit">
                        <p>
                            На главную
                        </p>
                    </button>
                </form>
                **</div>**
```